# Kobuki : Timed out while waiting for serial data stream [/mobile_base] on Indigo

Tags: turtlebot2, turtlebot, kobuki

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Using a turtlebot 2 on 14.04.2

I ran through the install section at http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot/Tutorials/indigo/Turtlebot%20Installation and the network setup.

When running:

roslaunch turtlebot_bringup minimal.launch

The kobuki base makes it's startup noise, then, a few seconds later it makes it's shutdown noise. With the following error message being produced on the console:

[ERROR] [1428974938.134654823]: Kobuki : Timed out while waiting for serial data stream [/mobile_base]

I get the same error when I try the kobuki node by itself:

$ roslaunch kobuki_node minimal.launch

setting /run_id to 0d2810f0-e247-11e4-8a15-0024d76aae74
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [22493]
started core service [/rosout]
process[mobile_base_nodelet_manager-2]: started with pid [22510]
process[mobile_base-3]: started with pid [22511]
process[diagnostic_aggregator-4]: started with pid [22546]
[ERROR] [1428975556.731802475]: Kobuki : Timed out while waiting for serial data stream [/mobile_base].
[ERROR] [1428975568.331793777]: Kobuki : Timed out while waiting for serial data stream [/mobile_base].

This turtlebot was previously working in Furte.

Any ideas?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207099/kobuki-:-timed-out-while-waiting-for-serial-data-stream-%5B/mobile_base%5D-on-indigo/) by [MichaelGregg](https://answers.ros.org/users/17861/michaelgregg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2015-04-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the end, powering off, then powering back on my turtlebot laptop seemed to be the fix.

The suspicion was usb bus issues with the kinect and the kobuki on the same usb port.

---

Originally posted by [MichaelGregg](https://answers.ros.org/users/17861/michaelgregg/) with karma: 41 on 2015-04-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0